# Расположение composer на вебсервере

Tags: composer

Если ставить composer локально, ето папка composer.json и папка vendor должны оказаться выше директории диступной из web после установки?

Иначе это небезопасно т.к. любой зависимости сможет посмотреть если их специально htaccess не закрыть?

Comment: а почему просто не удалить эти файлы после развертывания в production? зачем они там нужны?

Comment: @так там autoload.php подгружается а в composer.json указаны версии пакетов